# google script function depend what sheet is select to work. I can't find the issue

Tags: javascript

I have an app that uses google sheets as a backend and scrip as a spa with vuejs.
When I render objects. It works with some sheets but not with others. I can't understand why.

```
//In backend i have this global variables
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ovZyohZIWjkzXQD6mTcWRY8tphITLG5ck-4DbEQM3NA')
var PAGAMENTOS_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('pagamentos');
var CONFIG_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('config');
var USERS_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('cadastros');
var PRODUTOS_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('produtos');
var OFERTAS_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('ofertas');
var PEDIDOS_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('pedidos');
var FEIRAS_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('feiras');//when i change the name it sheet works
var LOGRADOUROS_TABLE = ss.getSheetByName('logradouros');

//this function
function getFeiras(){
var data = getTableData(FEIRAS_TABLE); 
  var feiras = [];   
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){ 
    var feira = {
      local: data[i][0], 
      endereco: data[i][1],
      data: data[i][2],
      dia: data[i][3],
      id: data[i][7],      
    }        
    feiras.push(feira); 
  }  
  return {
      success: true,
      feiras:feiras,
      mensagem: "Feiras renderizadas!", 
    };
}

//in the front end i have 

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(renderFeiras).getFeiras();

function renderFeiras(response){
      app.feiras = response.feiras;
}
```

This works with almost all sheet's name, except with two where the response result is null. The example works with sheet 'produtos', 'cadastros' and 'ofertas' but not with 'feiras', 'pedidos'
Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Without understand what hapen, i solve this by convert date values in text.....

Comment: Second solution  was change `data: data[i][2]` to `data: "'"+data[i][2]+"'"`